# Permutation around round table.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Their are $5$ boys and $3$ girls sitting around a round table.
>   In how many ways can they all sit around the table so that
>   no girls are together ?

$a.)\ 1220 \\
b.)\ 1400 \\
c.)\ 1420 \\
\color{green}{d.)\ 1440 }\\$

By circular permutation i thought it would be 
$(5-1)!\times (3-1)!=48$

But the answer given is $d.)$

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first seat the boys in a circle in $4!$ ways.

We can seat the girls in the 5 gaps between the boys in $\binom{5}{3}\cdot3!=5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways;

so there are $4!\cdot\binom{5}{3}\cdot3!=24\cdot10\cdot6=1440$ ways to seat them.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is a circular table, we use the ordinary convention that arrangements equivalent by a rotation are to be considered the same.  Equivalently, we can assume that one of the chairs is a throne and Alicia sits there.

Her left neighbour (a boy) can be chosen in $5$ ways, and for each of these ways her right neighbour can be chosen in $4$ ways, for a total of $(5)(4)$.

For every such arrangement, we are left with $5$ seats in which to put the remaining people.  Think of where the remaining boys will sit. There are $3$ placees. These determine $4$ "gaps" (including the two endgaps) into which we must slip the two girls, one girl per gap. **Choosing** the gaps can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, and then the girls can be permuted in $2!$ ways and the boys in $3!$ ways. That gives a total of $(5)(4)\binom{4}{2}(2!)(3!)$.

Note that the argument works generally.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to assign the gender.

1) BGBGBGBB (3 boys sit together)

2) BGBGBBGB (max 2 boys sit together)

Each has $3!\times5!=720$ different ways.